# Inrush current limiter 230V AC 16A (~325V DC 3,6kW ) - low power losses - safe

Tags: rectifier, high-current, inrush-current

I need an Inrush-Current limiter and struggling with a good starting point. Basically I was thinking about using a NTC which then get short-circuited by a relais after a short period of time to minimize losses. Any helpful thoughts on this? What is best used as a trigger for the relais? Voltage drop across something? Current itself? Just time? Pros/Cons?

Comment: Have you tried googling images for circuits: https://www.google.com/search?q=inrush+current+limiter&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAmoVChMIs-Xry-HLyAIVy78UCh2sPQ_O&biw=1298&bih=898

Comment: What is connected to the DC bus? Altrough it has no sense to use PTC, since you will get the same inrush as without PTC.

Comment: a wireless power transmitter

Answer (score 1):

I do use this http://electronics-diy.com/soft-start-for-power-supply.php for toroid transformer, part of dc bus for stepper motor drivers. It works great. The basic idea is to limit the inrush current due to magnetization and also due to large capacitor that is discharged at begining. ou can use similar circuit to slowly charge the capacitor and then to switch to operation. A good way to go would be using another pair of contacts of the relay, disconnecting the load.
1. the relay is open: resistors limit the current to the cap, load is disconnected
2. at certain delay, the relay closes and bypass the resistors, while the other contacts connect the load.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at an ICL (inrush current limiter). It's like a PTC but opposite. It starts off with high resistance and lowers it's resistance as it gets hot.

http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/circuit-protection/inrush-current-limiters-icl/656273

Comment: Isn't heir highest value only 10ohm? That would still be more than double than 16amps on 325volt - or not?

Comment: @muhkuh The device is meant to control the inrush current for a capacitor. Yes the initial inrush will be on the order of 32 amps but that will be for less then a second due to the charging characteristics of the capacitor. The general idea is to avoid the 3250A inrush for a 0.1 ohm ESR capacitor alone.

Comment: but this would blow the standard used 16ampere fuse

Comment: @muhkuh This depends on the kind of fuse. A slow blow fuse can withstand double the current rating for up to several seconds. Also if your circuit is running at 16A and you have a 16A fuse then your circuit is poorly designed. Could you provide more information on your circuit.

Comment: the wall plugs here are secured with 16amp fuses.